# UICollectionview SelectItem programmatically not changing background

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, uicollectionview, mvvmcross

I have a UICollectionView with images. The user can select (multiselect) the images. When the user taps a single image, everything works fine. The SelectedBackgroundView is visible and on tap again, the normal image is visible.

But my problem is, I have a option for the user "Select all". In that i want to select all items programmatically. With following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < CollectionView.NumberOfItemsInSection(0); i++)
{
    var ip = NSIndexPath.FromItemSection(i, 0);
    CollectionView.SelectItem(ip, false, UICollectionViewScrollPosition.None);
}
```

The following method returns the correct number for the selected items:

```
var number = CollectionView.GetIndexPathsForSelectedItems().Length;
```

But the UI is not changing to the SelectedBackgroundView.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `SelectItem` does not cause the display to be updated; it just changes the `Selected` property of the `UICollectionViewCell` therefore updating the selected index set in the collection view.

What I do is override the `Selected` property of my `UICollectionViewCell` implementation and adjust the UI at that point:

```
public class MyCell : UICollectionViewCell
{
    // ...
    public override bool Selected
    {
        get { return base.Selected; }
        set
        {
            base.Selected = value;
            // change the state of the selected background
            imageBackground.Image = LoadAnImage(value ? "BackgroundOn" : "BackgroundOff");
        }
    }
}
```

This way ensures that the UI is updated at all possible points when the selected state of the cell changes, either by user interaction or programmatically calling `SelectItem` or `DeselectItem` on the collection view.

I do not personally use the `SelectedBackgroundView` property on a cell (I do my own layering, most of the time), but you may have to manually bring that view to the front yourself in a similar `Selected` property override.

Comment: I do not think this is absolutely correct way to handle selection. You can read more info here (navigate to Managing the Visual State for Selections and Highlights section) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCellsandViews/CreatingCellsandViews.html

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The Selected-Property did the trick for me. The Delegate-Methods are also a good solution, but not in my case.